# Compilation error while implementing Trait

Tags: scala, traits

Given this code: (no matter whether it doesn't make much sense)

```
    object Test {

          def main(args: Array[String]) {
           (new FooImpl2()).foo()
          }

          trait Foo {
            def foo()
          }

          trait M extends Foo {
            abstract override def foo() {println("M"); super.foo()}
          }

          abstract class FooImpl1 extends Foo {

          }

          class FooImpl2 extends FooImpl1 with M{
            override def foo() {println("Impl2")}
          }

    }
```

At compile time, this error occurs:

```
error: overriding method foo in trait M of type ()Unit;
method foo needs `abstract override' modifiers
override def foo() {println("Impl2")}
```

So at this place:

```
class FooImpl2 extends FooImpl1 with M{
    override def foo() {println("Impl2")}
}
```

Why doesn't `override` apply on `FooImpl1` (in order to provide a concrete implementation for abstract trait method)? It seems like it matches the trait method's instead...and obviously there's a huge conflict with the pattern "`abstract override`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M needs to be mixed-in after the concrete def (in linearization order).

Comment: Thanks :) So that explains why this code works:         class FooImpl1 extends Foo {
    def foo() {println("Impl")}
  }  

  class FooImpl2 extends FooImpl1 with M{
    override def foo() {println("Impl2")}
  }                                                                         since concrete method implementation is defined before M is mixed-in.